# moving shape in canvas using eventlistener

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have the code done, but the only thing i am unable to do is , that i only want the circle to move when the mouse enters in the circle then it follows the mouse around as show n below . 
The circle starts to move when i enter the window , i want it to start to move when i enter the circle 
I am unable to apply the syntax here , any help would be appreciated

```html
<!--
For this assignment, create an event listener that is triggered when the mouse 
moves through the #cont div. Using pageVars and offsets, dynamically set the
top and left style properties of the #circ1 div so that the circle follows the 
user's mouse.
-->


<html>

<head>
  <title>basic_canvas</title>

  <style>
    div {
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    #cont {
      margin: 0 auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 800px;
      height: 600px;
    }
    
    .col {
      width: 365px;
      height: 380px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: rgba(110, 25, 75, 0.2);
    }
    
    #c2 {
      left: 405px;
    }
    
    .lower {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      top: 400px;
    }
    
    .circ {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
    }
    
    .circ:hover {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    }
    
    .text {
      width: 360px;
    }
    
    #circ1 {
      top: 20px;
      left: 350px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    //global vars
    var mycanvas;
    var ctx;

    //make a ready handler for our page to trigger my javascript
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //event listener attached to the #cont element here
      $("#cont").mouseenter(function() {
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
          var x = e.pageX;
          var y = e.pageY;
          $("#circ1").css({
            "top": y,
            "left": x
          });
        });
      });

    });

    /*
     *  write a function called by the mousemove listener
     *  inside this function, calculate the x and y coordinates
     *  of the mouse and translate these to top and left css properties
     *  finally, set the top and left of the #circ1 element
     *  offsetX and offsetY are the same thing as mouseX and mouseY ->system variables
        
        
     *  this works for chrome
        var posX = e.offsetX;
        var posY = e.offsetY;
        
     *  this works for firefox
        var posX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var posY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
     * 
    */




    function degToRad(deg) {
      radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;
      return radians;
    }

    function getRandomFloat(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="cont">
    <div class="col" id="c1">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quam turpis, maximus sit amet gravida ut, vestibulum nec lectus. Sed risus est, ultricies non quam in, tristique bibendum augue. Etiam accumsan est viverra lectus feugiat interdum. Duis
        dignissim nisi consectetur suscipit consectetur. Phasellus nulla augue, tincidunt ac pellentesque faucibus, iaculis a arcu. Mauris pretium, augue ut malesuada cursus, lorem mauris sodales sapien, vel mollis libero libero vel nisi. Nam viverra
        arcu at nibh vehicula, non sagittis arcu tincidunt.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col" id="c2">
      <div class="text">
        Aenean sagittis et nulla quis interdum. Nam est tellus, lobortis eget faucibus a, porta vel dolor. Nulla quam magna, volutpat ut malesuada quis, cursus et neque. Nulla facilisis rutrum eros, congue porta orci maximus vitae. Phasellus a sollicitudin sem.
        Maecenas vestibulum odio nec justo efficitur, quis consequat orci tempus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce mollis facilisis justo vitae auctor. Maecenas porttitor luctus urna, ultricies volutpat purus elementum sed. Mauris maximus sodales ante, ut
        lobortis libero faucibus quis. Cras turpis leo, vehicula sed mattis ac, dignissim egestas sem. Ut elementum a tellus vel faucibus.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lower" id="l1">

      <div class="circ" id="circ1"></div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this is not working for me on SO. Whem I'm adding jquery I get the console full of errors. This is the link to a [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/d32fe7dfa0e1826630c55dc893aec0e2/)

Changes I've made:

1. In JavaScript I'm using var `e.clientX-50` and `e.clientY-50`; instead of `pageX` and pageY. The -50 is because I want the mouse in the center of the circle. Otherwise I'll get the pointer in the upper left corner od the `.circ`
2. In CSS

I've added .circ{position:absolute;} otherwise the top and left properties are pointless. Please check the code to see the lines of code I've removed.

```js
 //global vars
    var mycanvas;
    var ctx;

    //make a ready handler for our page to trigger my javascript
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //event listener attached to the #cont element here
      //$("#cont").mouseenter(function() {
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
          console.log(e)
          var x = e.clientX-50;
          var y = e.clientY-50;
          $("#circ1").css({
            "top": y,
            "left": x
          });
        });
      });

    //});

    /*
     *  write a function called by the mousemove listener
     *  inside this function, calculate the x and y coordinates
     *  of the mouse and translate these to top and left css properties
     *  finally, set the top and left of the #circ1 element
     *  offsetX and offsetY are the same thing as mouseX and mouseY ->system variables
     *  this works for chrome
        var posX = e.offsetX;
        var posY = e.offsetY;

     *  this works for firefox
        var posX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var posY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
     * 
    */




    function degToRad(deg) {
      radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;
      return radians;
    }

    function getRandomFloat(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
```

```css
  div {
      position: absolute;
    }

    #cont {
      margin: 0 auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 800px;
      height: 600px;
    }

    .col {
      width: 365px;
      height: 380px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: rgba(110, 25, 75, 0.2);
    }

    #c2 {
      left: 405px;
    }

    .lower {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      /*top: 400px;*/
    }

    .circ {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
      position:absolute;
    }

    .circ:hover {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    }

    .text {
      width: 360px;
    }
    /*
    #circ1 {
      top: 20px;
      left: 350px;
    }*/
```

```html
<div id="cont">
    <div class="col" id="c1">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quam turpis, maximus sit amet gravida ut, vestibulum nec lectus. Sed risus est, ultricies non quam in, tristique bibendum augue. Etiam accumsan est viverra lectus feugiat interdum. Duis
        dignissim nisi consectetur suscipit consectetur. Phasellus nulla augue, tincidunt ac pellentesque faucibus, iaculis a arcu. Mauris pretium, augue ut malesuada cursus, lorem mauris sodales sapien, vel mollis libero libero vel nisi. Nam viverra
        arcu at nibh vehicula, non sagittis arcu tincidunt.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col" id="c2">
      <div class="text">
        Aenean sagittis et nulla quis interdum. Nam est tellus, lobortis eget faucibus a, porta vel dolor. Nulla quam magna, volutpat ut malesuada quis, cursus et neque. Nulla facilisis rutrum eros, congue porta orci maximus vitae. Phasellus a sollicitudin sem.
        Maecenas vestibulum odio nec justo efficitur, quis consequat orci tempus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce mollis facilisis justo vitae auctor. Maecenas porttitor luctus urna, ultricies volutpat purus elementum sed. Mauris maximus sodales ante, ut
        lobortis libero faucibus quis. Cras turpis leo, vehicula sed mattis ac, dignissim egestas sem. Ut elementum a tellus vel faucibus.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lower" id="l1">

      <div class="circ" id="circ1"></div>

    </div>

  </div>
```